# Find which dynamically created button has been clicked

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to create something like stackoverflow.com tag cloud.
I am able to display the tags but stuck on how to capture which tag element cancel button was clicked.

The cancel buttons are created dynamically using jquery on click of `btnAdd`.

```
$("#<%=btnAdd.ClientID%>").on('click',function(){
  var tagText = $('#<%=txtTag.ClientID%>').val();
  var btnCancel = '<button class="btn btn-default">X</button>';

  var tagTextDiv ='<div class="tagElement">' + tagText + btnCancel +'</div>';

  $("#divTagCloud").append(' ' + tagTextDiv);
});
```

HTML is

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
   <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnAdd"/>
</div>


<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
   <div id="divTagCloud"></div>
</div>
```

I want to remove the tag i.e corresponding `tagTextDiv` on click of corresponding cancel button.

How to do this ?

Comment: Could you please add an example of your HTML structure to the question.

Comment: are you able to show the jquery that output (after the asp.net tags have been rendered?)

Comment: yes , The tags are displayed after every button Add click

Comment: What/where is `tagTextDiv`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0ak5obL1/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the tag and button elements as jquery objects instead of just strings. That allows you to attach event handlers before inserting them into the DOM.

```
$("#<%=btnAdd.ClientID%>").on('click',function(){
    var tagText = $('#txtTag').val();
    // Create the tag and cancel button elements
    var btnCancel = $('<button class="btn btn-default">X</button>');
    var tagTextDiv = $('<div class="tagElement">' + tagText + '</div>');
    // insert the cancel button into the tag element
    tagTextDiv.append(btnCancel);
    // attach an onclick event handler to the cancel button, that removes the tag.
    btnCancel.click(function() {
        // "this" is the element that the event handler is attached to, in this case, the cancel button
        // get its' parent (the tag text div) and remove that from the DOM
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    // finally, insert the new tag into the DOM
    $("divTagCloud").append(tagTextDiv);
});
```